# What is the alternative for System.Windows.Forms library since this library is not available in .Net7.0 for cross platform

Tags: cross-platform, .net-7.0, .net-4.8

I was using the Syetem.Windows.Forms library in my .Net Framework project but now I have migrated it to.Net7.0 and now "System.Windows.Forms" is not available in .net7.0.
since I wanted to make my project compatible for cross platform that why I do not want to add this property in my .csproj file -

```
 <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
 <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
```

which will make it only window specific project.

Below is the code, where I am using the Window.Form library PropertyTab class and overriding the Bitmap, TagName, GetProperties properties and method.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace MARKEM.LocalisationServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// LocalisedPropertyTab inherits from PropertyTab so to allow customization of 
    /// the properties displayed in the PropertyGrid.
    /// </summary>
    public class LocalisedPropertyTab : PropertyTab
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The Property Tab's display name.
        /// </summary>
        private string m_tabName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new PropertyTab with a specified display name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tabName">Name of the PropertyTab.</param>
        public LocalisedPropertyTab(string tabName) : base()
        {
            m_tabName = tabName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the name of the tab.
        /// </summary>
        public override string TabName {
            get {
                return m_tabName;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a Bitmap for the Tab.
        /// Currently returns an empty 16x16 bitmap as we don't need a visual display
        /// when there is only one tab.
        /// </summary>
        public override Bitmap Bitmap {
            get {
                return new Bitmap(16,16);
            }
        }

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(object component, Attribute[] attrs) {
                     //Removed the code
            } 

    }//end of class
}//end of namespace
```

Is there any alternative library provided by the Microsoft to use in place of System.Windows.Forms

Check for the alternative, still didn't find any solution regarding it.

Comment: Well, WinForms is not cross-platform. Not sure how you imagine a `PropertyTab` to work on other platforms than windows.

Comment: It not the WinForms project. it is class library project in that I had previously added the reference of "System.Windows.Forms" to use the "PropertyTab" class, now I have migrated to .Net 7.0 and wanted to make my project compatible to cross platform, so in that case what alternative I have use in this case.

Comment: Sure, but the project refers to WinForms because PropertyTab is a WinForms class. A PropertyTab can't be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer here is: there is no cross-platform alternative for `System.Windows.Forms`. As its name says, it's for Windows.

Even if you have a class library that's not a WinForms executable but does have a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` it's impossible to make the library cross-platform. The class you use, `PropertyTab`, is a WinForms-only class, so inherently not cross-platform.

For cross-platform UI-development you'd have to use a cross-platform framework, like [Maui](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui), or [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/desktop), to name a few.